# How to make parent div activate styling of child div for hover and active

Tags: css, laravel, user-interface, tailwind-css

I made this style for side bar navigation

[image]

I made a box and used transform to hide it on the left side, to get the curved border effect.

On hover, active ect

- Border button -> bg-green-300
- text-green-300 for icon and text
- font-semibold for text only

```
<a href="/dashboard">
    <div class="flex flex-row space-x-8 w-72 text-lg pb-3 text-gray-200"> 
        
        <div class="h-8 w-8 rounded transform -translate-x-7 hover:bg-green-300"></div>

        <div class="flex flex-row items-center space-x-8 transform -translate-x-10 -translate-y-1">
            <i class="bi bi-columns-gap hover:text-green-300 transform translate-x-1"></i>
            <h2 class="hover:font-semibold hover:text-green-300 transform translate-y-1 text-base">Dashboard</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Is there something I can add to the main div to activate the hover effect in each child element at same time?

Right now it works only when I hover over each individual element.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use group-hover state

1. Add **group** class to your parent element (anchor-tag in your case)
2. Replace `hover:` with `group-hover:`

Worth to mention not every property supports group-hover, so there can be situation, where you may need to extend core plugins. More info about group-hover [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover)

DEMO https://play.tailwindcss.com/dzacJTR76X

Comment: Please update your answer with code example. Demo doesn't enough.

Answer (score 46):

Use `group` in `parent` and `group:hover` in `child`

##### Code Structure:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group-hover:... "/>
    <div class="group-hover:... "/>
</div>
```

#### Example:

```
<div class="group flex ">
    <div class="rounded-full bg-black w-10 h-10 group-hover:bg-cyan-400 "></div>
    <i class="text-4xl ml-4 group-hover:bg-cyan-400 cursor-pointer ">Brighten me</i>
</div>
```

#### Output:

[image]

##### OnHover:

[image]

Comment: Now _that_ is like magic, tailwind is so clever!

Comment: Although I was fighting with focus, the problem was the same for me. There was one more caveat - no matter what I did, nothing made it change as I wanted. I discovered my CSS file had this: `* {
  color: var(--custom-color);` After I removed it, my tailwind color was applied properly