# How to change stroke color when button was hovered in tailwind css

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I wanna ask something about how to change stroke color when button was hovered in tailwind, so I already made this code like this:

```
<button class="w-[3.125rem] h-[3.125rem] flex items-center justify-center rounded-full border-2 border-[#969696] hover:border-0 hover:bg-white">
  <span>
    <svg width="8" height="14" viewBox="0 0 8 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M7 1L1 7L7 13" stroke="#969696" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
```

okey, in above my code is working no giving error or some weird things, but the problem is I don't know how to change the stroke of my `svg` when my button is hovered, I already try to make some piece of code to styling my stroke to change the color, and the code is like this:

```
<svg width="8" height="14" viewBox="0 0 8 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M1 1L7 7L1 13" stroke="#969696" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="hover:stroke-black" />
</svg>
```

everything is not okay in here, the problem is I must move my cursor on my `svg` to change the stroke but when I moving out my cursor from my `svg` only button change the background and my `svg` is not change the stroke, does anyone used to having problem like this? And how to solve this? I hope someone can explain this, before that thank you, oh ya I will attach the screenshot about my problem, so that everyone who read this getting more understand about my problem

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this should be tailwinds group-hover state as discussed in [How to make parent div activate styling of child div for hover and active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65946335/how-to-make-parent-div-activate-styling-of-child-div-for-hover-and-active)

Given that the solution could be something like this

```html
<button class="group w-[3.125rem] h-[3.125rem] flex items-center justify-center rounded-full border-2 border-[#969696] hover:border-0 hover:bg-white">
  <span>
    <svg width="8" height="14" viewBox="0 0 8 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M1 1L7 7L1 13" stroke="#969696" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="group-hover:stroke-black" />
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
```

Notice the `group` and `group-hover`.